# Firebase notification won`t sound or vibrate flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I have enabled firebase messaging on my futter app everything works fine but, when I receive the notification in my app it wont sound or vibrate, neither android or ios. I believe FCM does it by default, I also have "IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true)", but the notification just come mute. Do you guys have any Idea what could be happening? I searched for this situation but couldnt find anything about it. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

 String _homeScreenText = "Waiting for token...";

 final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

 static const String contato = "contato";

 TabController _tabController;

 @override
 void initState() {
    _tabController = new TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
    super.initState();

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
       onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
         print('on message $message');
       },
       onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
         print('on resume $message');
       },    
       onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
       print('on launch $message');
       },
      );

     _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
         const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
     _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
       .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
         print("Settings registered: $settings");
      });
     _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
       assert(token != null);
       setState(() {
     _homeScreenText = "Push Messaging token: $token";
     });
     print(_homeScreenText);
     });

     _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
     Firestore.instance.collection("pushtokens").document().setData({"devtoken": token});
     });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable sound on notification you need to add `sound: default` part in notification data like this:

```
{
  data: {
    google.sent_time: 1588863942303, 
    click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, 
    google.original_priority: high,
    collapse_key: YourPackageName,
    google.delivered_priority: high,
    sound: default,
    from: YourSenderId,
    google.message_id: 0:1588863942508709%a91ceea4a91ceea4,
    google.ttl: 60
  },
  notification: {}
}
```

Comment: @Teh Sunn Liu Where exactly do we add this? Inside flutter or Firebase? Kindly explain

Comment: @Lefty This answer is not posted by me :). I'm just an editor. This can be added to your HTTP request usually from the server. follow the link to know more https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidconfig

Comment: @Teh Sunn Liu , its all good, I did manage to get it working. Thanks

Comment: I added it to the ```notification``` and it worked as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can add something like this for the http request to send the notification.

**But first thing you need to check is whether your phone is allowing the app to notify.** which lost my most part of time.

```
{
    topic: topic,
    android: {
      priority: "high",
      notification: {
        defaultSound: true,
        //sound: "default",
      },
    },
    data: {
      somedata: "value",
    },
    notification: {
      title: title,
      body: description,
      imageUrl: "https://i.picsum.photos/id/999/536/354.jpg?hmac=xYKikWHOVjOpBeVAsIlSzDv9J0UYTj_tNODJCKJsDo4",
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sending messages from my node (Typescript) backend. I only needed to add the `sound` property to the `notification` portion of the message payload. I'm using the Firebase Message flutter SDK and didn't need to add any special configuration there.

Below is how it looks in Typescript (but the message JSON is all that matters).

```js
let tokens = ...
let message = {
    message: {
        notification: {
            title: title,
            body: body,
            sound: 'default', // <----- All I needed
        },
        data: {
            ...
        },
    }
}

firebase.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, message)
```